# How to read bad lines in csv files using Pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The csv file has the following structure:

```
a,b,c
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
a,b,c,d
a,b,c
```

if I use `file = pd.read_csv('Desktop/export.csv',delimiter=',')`, it will throw a tokenizing error like this:
`pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 3, saw 10`

I do NOT want to skip bad lines. I want to read the csv with all columns and create a dataframe that looks like:

```
unnamed column1, unnamed column2, ....... unnamed column 7
a,b,c
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
a,b,c,d
a,b,c
```

How can I load the bad lines in the csv files?

Comment: Re https://stackoverflow.com/q/75242879 ``drop database `b'MavenFuzzyFactory'`;``. Just enclose the identifier that has not normally allowed characters in backticks.

Comment: if that doesn't work, likely there are other characters you aren't seeing in the name; do `select SCHEMA_NAME,hex(SCHEMA_NAME) from information_schema.SCHEMATA;` to see what they might be.  the name you report would just have 62274D6176656E46757A7A79466163746F727927

Answer (score 0):

You can use the error_bad_lines set to false.

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv('Desktop/export.csv', delimiter=',',error_bad_lines=False)
```